# How can I make an alias for a method with variable arguments?

Tags: c++

I have defined a abstract class that has two methods using variable arguments. Some implementations will implement the same functionality for both. Of course, I don't want to duplicate any code, so I'd like to have some kind of alias in that implementation.

```
class ILogger {
    public: 
        virtual void logf(const char *format, ...) = 0;
        virtual void printf(const char *format, ...) = 0;
};

class SerialLogger : public ILogger {
    public: 
        void printf(const char *format, ...);
        void logf(const char *format, ...);
}
```

My (naive) implementation would say something like this:

```
void SerialLogger::logf(const char *format, ...) {
    // do the "va" stuff
}

void SerialLogger::printf(const char *format, ...) {
   return logf(format, ...);
}
```

This doesn't work, but how can I do something like that, without having to duplicate the code that uses the `va_` calls?

Comment: There is no way to "forward" C style variadic arguments, you need to define additional functions that accept a `va_list` as argument

Comment: Consider template [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead. Or use a "stream"-like method using `<<`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Template parameter packs and virtual functions don't mix.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah that's true. So streams and `<<` is really the recommended way in that case. That's usually what I do myself. :)

Comment: @UnholySheep and would it be possible to do some preprocessor magic here?